# IMAP search for email address in the from field

Tags: python, imap, exchange-server, imaplib

I am trying to search and filter my imap mails using python's imaplib. I am running into a quite strange problem with the search command, searching for email addresses in the `FROM` field. I have the following script,

```
print('search with name')
status, results = con.search(None, '(FROM "Shrikant Sharat")')
if status == 'OK':
    if results[0]:
        mid = results[0].split()[0]
        print('mail id', mid)
        print(con.fetch(mid, '(UID BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])'))
    else:
        print('No results yielded')
else:
    print('unable to search', results)

print()
print('search with email')
status, results = con.search(None, '(FROM "shrikantsharat.k@gmail.com")')
if status == 'OK':
    if results[0]:
        mid = results[0].split()[0]
        print('mail id', mid)
        print(con.fetch(mid, '(UID BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])'))
    else:
        print('No results yielded')
else:
    print('unable to search', results)
```

for which, I get the following result,

```
search with name
mail id 2155
('OK', [('2155 (UID 5340 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] {54}', 'From: Shrikant Sharat <shrikantsharat.k@gmail.com>\r\n\r\n'), ' FLAGS (\\Seen))'])

search with email
No results yielded
```

Why does the second search fail? The email address is present in the `From` field as shown by the previous search. The second search should've matched this mail right?

Is this not the way to search for email address in the `From` field? I am pulling my hair apart on this one. Any ideas?

**Edit** If relevant, I am trying this with an IMAP server exposed by MS Exchange (2007, I think).

Comment: I've tested your code, and it works against my local Cyrus imapd as well as Gmail. Works with both `(FROM "user@domain.com")` and `(FROM user@domain.com)` syntax. What brand of imap server are you accessing?

Comment: @samplebias, This is the IMAP server from an MS Exchange server. **Edit**: with ssl

Comment: hmm, I somehow thought it'd be Exchange (unfortunately I don't have access to one). If you happen to have an IMAP client where search works (pine, etc) perhaps snoop and compare the protocol commands issued?

Comment: @simplebias, I don't have pine, but I have mutt and thunderbird configured to connnect to this IMAP server. Are you suggesting I snoop the packets sent using wireshark or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this as your filter:

```
(HEADER FROM "shrikantsharat.k@gmail.com")
```