# How can I search a mail in my imap folder starting from an EML file with python?

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to select a specific mail in my imap folder without having a clear identifier. The only thing I have is a plaintext copy of the mail saved as an eml file.

I tried to load the mail from the file using the `email` module but I keep getting errors whenever I run the search function of the `imaplib` module starting from the data contained in the mail.

In this instance I'm assuming that the mail comes from the current mailbox.

This is the code I'm using now

```
import imaplib, email

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER)
m.login(IMAP_USER, IMAP_PWD)
m.select()

mail_file = open('./file.eml')
raw_mail = mail_file.read()
mail = email.message_from_string(raw_mail)

resp, items = m.search(None, '(FROM "' + mail["FROM"] +'")')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py353\lib\imaplib.py", line 707, in search
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py353\lib\imaplib.py", line 1180, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py353\lib\imaplib.py", line 1011, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Error in IMAP command SEARCH: Unknown argument DATE (0.000 + 0.000 secs).']`
```

How should I do this and what filters can I use to have a reasonable chance of getting exactly the mail I want in the results?

Edit: as requested my `mail['FROM']` returns `'test sender\n\t<sender@domain.com>'`

I made a test hardcoding a similar format and removing the special characters but of course I'm returned a different mail with matched sender.
Also I'm trying to get to the correct mail without altering any data in the most automatic way possible.

Comment: Edited as requested by @stovfl

Comment: *`'test sender\n\t'`*: This does not explain the `Error ... SEARCH: Unknown argument DATE ...`. I would prefer to use it without the trailing `\n\t`. Left the Question: **Where does  `Unknown argument DATE` come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IMAP search for email address in the from field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877529/imap-search-for-email-address-in-the-from-field)

Comment: @stovfl I have literally no clue about that, except for the login variables which I left out the code is exactly as written.

Comment: *"the code is exactly as written."*: This ist different, . **have you tried it like in the dup Answer?**