# Find messages by sender IMAP.search()

Tags: python, email, search, imap, imaplib

I use the imaplib library to work with emails. I want to find all emails from one person. The next code doesn't work for all messages:

```
    typ, data = con.search(None, 'FROM "name.surname@testmail.com"')
```

sometimes I need to set something like this to find that messages:

```
    typ, data = con.search(None, 'FROM "Surname, Name"')
```

and I cannot find a message by email. If I understand correct, it's only for messages in html format.

```
    print(message['From'])
    print(type(message['From']))
```

That code will print next:

```
    "Surname, Name" <name.surname@testmail.com>
    <class 'str'>
```

Why search function doesn't search in this string all possible mentions? Doesn't it work like a normal string search? How should I search, if I want to find all messages with email '@testmail.com', not from a specific person?

Comment: The first search searches for messages whose From field contains the substring name.surname@testmail.com, neither more nor less. The question seems underspecified and should be clarified or closed. Do your messages even contain that string?

Comment: Yes. I have only one message in my Inbox\TestFolder. It is from 'name.surname@testmail.com'. search(None, 'FROM "name.surname@testmail.com"') returns nothing, search(None, 'FROM "Surname, Name"') returns that message. It is very strange, that's why I asked a question on stackoverflow, I didn't find any info about my strange case in google.

Comment: It seems, that search function is searching substring only in first part (between double quotes) and ignoring other part of the string with email address. I can find my message even if I will search by one coma: con.search(None, 'FROM ","'). Maybe, the problem is with that quotation marks?

Comment: Note: search is implemented by your server, not by the client; if the search is wonky, it's because your server has mis-implemented it.  What server implementation are you using?

Comment: The correct quote character is ".

Comment: @Max I think you are right. I find out, that server is parsing emails and taking name and surname from it (if I send a message, then msg['From'] contains only email address, "Surname, Name" string appears later). So I think, that server searches only in that substring. But I still don't know how to force server to search in the hole string, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an answer here: [IMAP search for email address in the from field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877529/imap-search-for-email-address-in-the-from-field)

Just use next as a filter:

```
(HEADER FROM "name.surname@testmail.com")
```